# Buggy menu button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, drop-down-menu

very new to programming
just a bug im having with my collaspable meanu
looks fine on browers firefox responsive design view on 320px width 
but when i load i on my mobile phone firefox brower it bugs it a squareblock
im new to all this and trying to use the bootstrap 4 to overcome my lack of javascript knowledge
plus i couldnt figure out how to use that jfiddle sorry :( so heres the code and img of what i getting

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
        <div class="row header">

                <div class="col-xs-3 pull-xs-right">
                <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar2">&#9776;
                </button>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <img src="images/emblem.gif" class="img-fluid pull-xs-left" alt="emblem">
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <h2>Systems</h2>
                    <p>Driving School</p>
                </div>

        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="exCollapsingNavbar2">                
            <ul class="nav nav-stacked nav-pills">
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#area">Area</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#deals">Deals</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

and my css

```
body {
position: relative;
}

 /**** NAVBAR/HEADER ****/

.navbar {
     padding: 0;

} 

.header {
    background-color: #232323;    
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

button {
    color: white;
 } 

button:focus {
    outline: 1px solid;

}   

a {
    color: dimgrey;
}

.header {
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

.header p {
   color: dimgrey;
}

.header img {
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

.header .col-xs-3 {
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

heres the result on firefoxbrower responsive design view

what i want :
[image]

and my mobile phone browser why is menu block white?(firefox) :

[image]

Comment: bootstrap 4..you sure using bootstrap 4?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css">

Comment: so i did a fresh start and simply cut and paste the template from the bootstrap 4 website http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/

Comment: stills bugs. must be bootstrap 4 issue. i'll have to think of an easier layout to manage;'(

Comment: seems icons are not loading in your mobile..

Answer (score 0):

yep, tried it on another phone and worked on theirs
time for new phone